# Восстановление удаленных данных с андроид

Tags: восстановление

Можно ли восстановить данные с андроид после сброса до заводских настроек ??? Резервных копии и облако нет.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, нельзя.

Вероятно, данные поддаются восстановлению, так как некоторые устройства для быстроты очистки просто помечают области памяти как неиспользуемые: то есть данные фактически не стёрты, но записать туда новое — можно. Но это уже вопрос к создателям ОС, навряд ли удастся получить ответ.

Сохраняйте нужное перед сбросом!